# How can I programmatically set "List Content" and "List Object" permissions on AD OU entries?

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory

I'd like to set `List Content` and `List Object` options for an AD (Active Directory, Windows Server 2008 R2) OU for a particular user group using C# (.NET 4.0).

I managed to set the `gPOptions` and `gPLink`properties according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219957.aspx), but I did not find an example of how to set `List Content` and `List Object`. Setting the other two properties works as shown below:

[...]

```
byte[] binaryForm = new byte[ groupPrincipal.Sid.BinaryLength ];
groupPrincipal.Sid.GetBinaryForm( binaryForm, 0 );
IdentityReference identityReference =
    new SecurityIdentifier( binaryForm, 0 );
PropertyAccessRule propertyAccessRule =
    new PropertyAccessRule(
        identityReference,
        AccessControlType.Allow,
        PropertyAccess.Read,
        new Guid( "...value provided by MSDN link..." ) );
...
// ouEntry is of type DirectoryEntry
ouEntry.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule( propertyAccessRule );
ouEntry.CommitChanges();

...
// Same for gPLink with the corresponding GUID
```

Please ask if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List content` and `List object` have to be set somewhat differently:

```
...
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule activeDirectoryAccessRule =
    new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(
        identityReference,
        ActiveDirectoryRights.ListChildren | ActiveDirectoryRights.ListObject,
        AccessControlType.Allow,
        ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.None );
...
```

This `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule` has to be added to the corresponding `DirectoryEntry` as in the question above.